# Is standard deviation an accurate measure of uncertainty when the independent variable is unchanged?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, uncertainty

I have collected data over time for the value of a dependent variable, which depends on a non-time variable. For each measurement (with a set value for the independent variable), would it be appropriate to state the uncertainty for that data point as the standard deviation of the values collected over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in the variability of the cdf of your random variable, probably that would be sufficient (depending on your question). This assumes some degree of stationarity.

However, note that the time points are likely not indepedent, but are rather serially correlated (you can test this by plotting the acf). Maybe read here for some ways to address that: [Most appropriate way to make a time series stationary? (i.e. remove serial correlation?)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32363/most-appropriate-way-to-make-a-time-series-stationary-i-e-remove-serial-corre)